# Jquery 3.6.0 vulnerability using Semgrep scanning

Tags: javascript, jquery, security

recently I have did a code scanning and there are some vulnerabilities that were reported for jquery.js that I am using for my website. Version is 3.6.0.

- Bracket object notation with user input is present, this might allow an attacker to access all properties of the object and even it's prototype, leading to possible code execution.
  For example :

  a) `Expr.pseudos[i] = createButtonPseudo(i);`

  b) `for (i = 0, l = events[type].length; i < l; i++) {`

Is this considered as a false vulnerability ? Or upgrading to the latest version will solve the issue ? Thank you.

Comment: This vulnerability is highlighting user-input used in accessing a POJS object. It's not relevant to jQuery, therefore upgrading the library is unlikely to make a difference - unless those lines of code are removed, which, again, is unlikely. For more info on the vulnerability, see this reference: https://github.com/eslint-community/eslint-plugin-security/blob/main/docs/the-dangers-of-square-bracket-notation.md

Comment: I see. Does sanitizing the user-input resolve this vulnerability since we cannot change anything from jquery side ?

Comment: Yes, that's about all that you could do in this instance.